# Calfw calendar: how to apply different colors to just a type of Holidays?

Tags: calfw

I am happy with Calfw calendar, but I would like to see the "Solar Holidays" without confusing them with regular holidays.

By now I have set them as nil:

```
(setq holiday-solar-holidays nil)
```

But, could I apply them a different color?, like:

```
 '(cfw:face-holiday ((t :background "grey10" :foreground "#8c5353" :weight bold)))
```

But applying just for solar-holidays?

Comment: It has been awhile since I modified Calfw in my custom setup.  My recollection is that a request such yours would require modification of one or more of the functions to distinguish between certain holidays.  Most users of Emacs do not like to modify functions beyond using a simple `advice`.  As such, I generally do not write up answers any more that re-write a portion of the function(s) at issue ....  [Users generally worry that a future update by the author(s) will break the modification(s), and users do not want to be bothered with prospective maintenance in that regard.]

Comment: Thanks. As I know now there is not such option, I have asked in their github.

https://github.com/kiwanami/emacs-calfw/issues/118